# how to convert mean function to a character string in R

Tags: r

Hi I am writing a function where my input can take a list of functions like this

temp(mean,sum...)

and the function looks like this:

```
temp <- function(funs = NULL){

mtcars %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_if(is.numeric,funs,na.rm =TRUE)

}
```

the output will has xx_fn1, xx_fn2 etc but I want the column names to be xx_mean,xx_sum.

Tried `deparse(substitute(funs))` but nothing works.

Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

The function is ok (apart from misspelled `mtcars` name I think). You just need to use `funs()` function on your functions (just like in `summarise_if()`), e.g.

```
temp(funs(mean = mean))
```